# How do I change the top bar text color to white in my Ionic App?

Tags: ionic-framework

I changed the header to a darker color using this:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-royal">
```

When I run it on ios, the status bar text (time, carrier, battery, etc) at the top is black and difficult to see on the dark background.  How do I make this text white?

[image: Black text on dark header color]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With the plugin `statusbar` and `ngCordova` is pretty simple:

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);

app.run(function($cordovaStatusbar) {
  $cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(true);

  $cordovaStatusBar.style(1); //Light
  $cordovaStatusBar.style(2); //Black, transulcent
  $cordovaStatusBar.style(3); //Black, opaque
});
```

Take a look to the full article here:
http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/customizing-the-status-bar/

UPDATE - Without ngCordova:

Default Ionic project comes with the statusbar plugin installed. If you have this statement inside you run probably your project already have:

```
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
```

So the code become:

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']);

app.run(function() {
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
      StatusBar.style(1); //Light
      StatusBar.style(2); //Black, transulcent
      StatusBar.style(3); //Black, opaque
    }
});
```

UPDATE II

With a new version 2.x of the `cordova-plugin-statusbar` the `StatusBar.style()` method was substituted with these new methods:

```
StatusBar.styleLightContent();
StatusBar.styleBlackTranslucent();
StatusBar.styleBlackOpaque();
```

[Check the plugin's documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar)

Comment: This seemed to have changed in the newer versions of ionic, but I was able to use this info to figure out if I put ```StatusBar.style(1)``` in app.js, in the: ```.run(function($ionicPlatform) {...
if (window.StatusBar) {```
section it works.
I also removed the ```StatusBar.styleDefault();``` that was already in there.

Comment: By default, if you create a project using the CLI, the statusbar is already installed.

Comment: Changing text color does not work for status bar in ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 4 with angular app we can change the status bar color as well as its text color by following code [how to change status bar's text color](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/status-bar/)

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.splashScreen.hide();
  this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
});
```